# std::span constructor, libcxx vs libstdc++, template vs non-template?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, c++20

Strolling through [the code of libcxx's std::span](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/span#L218), I noticed that the first two value constructors (number 2 and 3 on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span)) were not templates.

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr span(pointer __ptr, index_type __count) : __data{__ptr}
    { (void)__count; _LIBCPP_ASSERT(_Extent == __count, "size mismatch in span's constructor (ptr, len)"); }
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr span(pointer __f, pointer __l) : __data{__f}
    { (void)__l;     _LIBCPP_ASSERT(_Extent == distance(__f, __l), "size mismatch in span's constructor (ptr, ptr)"); }
```

Instead of the template types `It` and `End` as shown on the cppreference page, they use the `pointer` type directly. So I was wondering whether or not the libcxx code is conforming.

I wanted a point of comparison, so I went ahead and looked at [the libstdc++ version](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/span#L157), and this one does use templates (and is quite a bit longer as a result).

```
template<contiguous_iterator _It>
requires __is_compatible_ref<iter_reference_t<_It>>::value
constexpr explicit(extent != dynamic_extent)
span(_It __first, size_type __count)
noexcept
: _M_extent(__count), _M_ptr(std::to_address(__first))
{
  if constexpr (_Extent != dynamic_extent)
    {
      __glibcxx_assert(__count == _Extent);
    }
}

template<contiguous_iterator _It, sized_sentinel_for<_It> _End>
requires __is_compatible_ref<iter_reference_t<_It>>::value
  && (!is_convertible_v<_End, size_type>)
constexpr explicit(extent != dynamic_extent)
span(_It __first, _End __last)
noexcept(noexcept(__last - __first))
: _M_extent(static_cast<size_type>(__last - __first)),
  _M_ptr(std::to_address(__first))
{
  if constexpr (_Extent != dynamic_extent)
    {
      __glibcxx_assert((__last - __first) == _Extent);
    }
}
```

Now, on the cppreference page, it is mentioned that these two constructors only participate in overload resolution if `It` satisfies *contiguous_iterator* and if the conversion from `std::iter_reference_t<It>` to `element_type` is at most a qualification conversion. To satisfy that, the libstdc++ code uses the `contiguous_iterator` concept as template typename ([defined here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/iterator_concepts.h#L605)) and the `__is_compatible_ref` requirement ([defined just above](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/span#L129)).

So, here is my question: is using the `pointer` type directly, instead of messing with concepts and requirements, actually conforming to the standard? Is the libcxx code correct and the libstdc++ code just overcomplicated?

I would also like to extend the question to the next three constructors (dealing with raw arrays and `std::array`, number 4, 5, and 6 on cppreference).

Comment: Are you aware that C++20 is currently under development? For example, [p0122r5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0122r5.pdf) specifies the constructor implemented by libc++ (`constexpr span(pointer ptr, index_type count); `), so it just seems that libc++ is not fully updated to the latest draft version.

Comment: The libcxx code seems incomplete to me.  `constexpr span(pointer __f, pointer __l)` is not enough if for instance I pass a pair of iterators to a vector.  I wonder if they just haven't finished the implementation yet.

Comment: @DanielLangr TBF, C++20 is done.  AFAIK it's just going through the final bureaucratic and editorial steps so nothing is really going to change now.

Comment: @NathanOliver Fair point.

Comment: the standard may be done, but implementations are still under development, some maybe started a while back from an old different version

Comment: Your first snippet seems to not handle `dynamic_extent` neither... so not finished implementation is probable IMO.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good catch, although that could just be handled in the assert, right?

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes I wasn't entirely sure, but from what I've seen, C++20 is pretty much done as NathanOliver points out. bolov makes a fair point though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator-constructor for `std::span` you mention was proposed in [P1394R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1394r4.pdf). According to [libc++ C++2a Status](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx2a_status.html), this paper has not yet been implemented in libc++.

libc++ implements [P0122R7](https://wg21.link/P0122R7), where there is that pointer-constructor (replaced by the iterator-constructor in P1394R4).

---

[P1872R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1872r0.pdf) is also related: `span` should have `size_type`, not `index_type`.

Answer (score 0):

> is using the pointer type directly, ... actually conforming to the standard?

No, such constructor is not sufficient to provide the template iterator constructor. The quoted / linked libc++ implementation does not conform to the upcoming standard.

libstdc++ template constructor is conforming.